# App using libgdx restarts whenever device rotates

Tags: android, rotation, libgdx

I made an app using accelerometer but problem is whenever it detects rotation of the screen, it goes to main menu.

I used following code to disable rotation but it still detects the rotation action and goes to mainmenu although it does not become landscape mode anymore.

```
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
    }
```

How can I prevent this rotation detection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` inside your activity tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file. That attribute defines that this specific activity should always be run in the portrait mode and thus Android will not try to change screen orientation on rotation.

Answer (score 2):

You will also want to add

```
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation"
```

in order to prevent restarts when the keyboard appears or is hidden.

If you use this, you can even remove `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` if you want your game to work in both landscape and portrait mode. See the libgdx wiki: https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration#The_.xml_File

Answer (score 2):

Kimi answer is correct, but if you want to run your game also on the Amazon device, then you should add the additional value "screenSize". So result would be:

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"`